# How do I center two objects in perspective plane

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I select these two objects with the perspective selection took, then I go to the align menu and center them horizontally.  The result is that the objects are no  longer in perspective.  You can see the top on is messed up. How do I center these two objects?
[image]
[image]

Comment: As far as I am aware the functionality you want doesn't exist.  I suspect you will have move the objects manually. [There's a tutorial here](https://youtu.be/kqGhpna1G08) which demonstrates how to move objects in perspective on the grid.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand your question, for example, you can not have a 3 perspective plane. A plane can only have 2 vanishing points.

But in general terms:

Scaling can not keep one object in the same perspective. Dimensions change, so the perspective change.

Imagine you have a tall table where you can see the top of it. If you "scale it" to be a giant table, you probably could see now the bottom part of it. You are in the same spot, the perspective grids remain the same because they depend on the viewer's point of view, but the table itself needs to be redrawn.

Comment: I have rewritten the question to focus on my real goal.